# ! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, captions, tikz-pic

I am just getting started with LateX, but i got an due date tomorrow.
When i compile my LateX file i get this error: ! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.
You can find my code below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=DIN]
\draw[->] [thick] (1, 2) -- (2,0);
\draw[->] (0, 0.8) -- (1.6,0.8);
\draw[->] [thick] (1, -2) -- (2,0);
\draw[->] [thick] (3, -2) -- (4,0);
\draw[->] [thick] (3, 2) -- (4,0);
\draw[->] [thick] (5, 2) -- (6,0);
\draw[->] [thick] (5, -2) -- (6,0);
\draw[->] [very thick] (0, 0) -- (7,0);
\node[right] at (7,0) {Problem};
\node[above] at (1,2) {Haupteinflussgröße};
\node[left] at (0, 0.8) {Nebeneinflussgröße};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ishikawa}
\label{Ishikawa}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following structure. It seems like you forgot to surround the `tikz` with a `figure` (a float). Btw, `[...]` is a placeholder for code.

```
[...]    

\usepackage{float} % for [H]

[...]

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[...]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption}
\label{label}
\end{figure}
```